# Trying to use a checkbox to define a comment as private or not. Using AJAX to post to PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

Currently it is returning an `[objectO` instead a YES or No value. Currently my checkbox is set up as a VARCHAR of length 3 but should I be using TINYINT or Boolean instead. If so, what do I have to change to get this working? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
("#add").click(function() {
    var chkval = "";

    if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
        chkval  = "Yes";
    } else {
        chkval = "No";
    }

    //define ajax config object
    var ajaxOpts = {
        type: "post",
        url: "../controller/addComment.php",
        data: "&module_ass=" + $("#leaveComment").find("input").val() + "&comment_body=" +              $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val() + "&private=" + $("#checkbox").val('chkval'),
        success: function(data) {
```

Comment: Please put your code into a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value of `chkval` so you need to just use it later :

```
("#add").click(function() {

                  var chkval = "";

                  if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
                    chkval  = "Yes";
                  } else {
                    chkval = "No";
                  }



                  //define ajax config object
                  var ajaxOpts = {
                    type: "post",
                    url: "../controller/addComment.php",
                    data: "&module_ass=" + $("#leaveComment").find("input").val() + "&comment_body=" +              $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val() + "&private=" +chkval,
                    success: function(data) {     ...
```

**UPDATE**
This was the complete code and the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4JFtw/) :

```
 $('#Volunteers').on('click','.accept', function(event){

   //if clickFlag = true then the button hasn't been clicked yet. 

    if(typeof this._clickFlag != 'undefined' && this._clickFlag){

       //alert if the button has been clicked once already
       alert("already accepted");

}else{

    //here I send some stuff to a database. I don't want to send it twice for the same 
    //row, which is why I need to prevent a double click
    alert('_clickFlag: '+this._clickFlag + ' First time processing!');
    this._clickFlag = true; 

}


});
```

Comment: @user3036812 glad it fixed it, please don't forget to mark it as a solution.

Comment: That worked fine and the module assignment and the text area is working asynchronously however, the checked input field is not updating asynchronously. Any ideas? Is it something to do with how I'm selecting the checkbox? Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QT84D/

Comment: @user3036812  something weird happened it seems that my answer has been changed? I also provided a jsfiddle which I don't see now...

Anyway please explain what you are trying to achieve, jsfiddle does not work it is not pointed to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use:

```
data: "&module_ass=" + $("#leaveComment").find("input").val() + "&comment_body=" +              $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val() + "&private=" + chkval,
```

Since the variable was assigned above.  You may also want to look into using a simple bool rather than the string values "Yes" and "No".